# PHP - 1 non-root folder, 1 php file inside. Need to disallow that script from changing anything outside that folder

Tags: php, security

I am supposed to provide an outside developer with access to our development server - hosted on GoDaddy.

I've created a folder in the root called bid-registration and have a file called bid-registration.php in there. It's all setup with its own database and FTP user.

However, I need a way to make sure the 3rd party developer can't access, create, delete, or modify any file outside of this directory.

How can I go about doing this?

I just need this folder to be a "walled garden".

Thanks very much for any help!

## EDIT

I should add that the 3rd party developer currently only has access to this folder via the FTP "root folder" parameter. However, I need to restrict what PHP files in that folder can do. I don't want the PHP files to be able to CRUD outside of that folder.

Something as simple as "../" could start compromising the server, depending on what code he adds/runs in the file I setup for him.

Comment: I'm not sure what godaddy gives you access to. You could create an FTP user for him, can you not set FTP permissions?

Comment: I've created an FTP user that can only access that folder, but he will be able to add code to the PHP file in that folder that could conceivably access/compromise/etc the rest of our server.

Comment: Is this something that could be done through HTACCESS or PHP.INI somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Create a FTP account, and set his home directory to that folder.  If he has ever developed anything (ever) he will most likely want FTP more the godaddy access.

Here is a godaddy help article on how to do it: http://help.godaddy.com/article/1236
Set the path to the directory you were talking about.

Comment: Seems he's concerned with PHP code being used to get around the FTP Access limits. I can't really think of how that would be done given that it should be governed by Apache's httpd permissions

Comment: Shouldn't be able to.  My understanding is that the FTP account would be linked to the folder (with user permissions).  Guess you could try and see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this requirement can be met using PHP on a shared host.

I'd propose to create another host for each partner, put each partner's scripts there and call those scripts using HTTP sub-requests (in case latency isn't too important).

If you are on your own managed server, suPHP might be helpful: http://www.suphp.org/Home.html .

Finally, don't forget that session files need to be protected too: Often in shared hosting environments, session file aren't properly isolated between shared hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do this but it's worth looking to see if selinux can do what you want just in case.